# ArrayList issue in HTTP Servlet

Tags: java, apache, rest, tomcat, servlets

I'm using Floodlight REST API in order to monitor a created virtual network in mininet. My goal is to display an arraylist of all the switches, hosts and statistics for the switches on a web browser using Apache Tomcat web server and HTTP Servlet. The application successfully displays all the switches and hosts, but fails when I'm adding the statistics for the switches.

When I'm mapping JSON string to java objects, the server returns the error in this line:

```
ArrayList<Switch> queues = mapper.readValue(queueJson, new TypeReference<ArrayList<Switch>>() {
    });
```

The error is:

```
HTTP status 500 - can not deserialize instance of java.util.arraylist out of start_object token
```

I have testet it without the switch statistics (Queues) part (with only hosts and devices) and everything works fine, but when I'm adding the queues ArrayList, it returns the above mentioned error.

How can I solve this issue ?. My code is shown below. Thanks in advance

```
package core;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.type.TypeReference;
import org.restlet.data.MediaType;
import org.restlet.resource.ClientResource;
import org.restlet.resource.ResourceException;

import pojos.Device;
import pojos.Switch;

@WebServlet("/PrintInfo")
public class PrintInfo extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public PrintInfo() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // create ClientResource object

    // List at the switches in the network
    ClientResource cResourceSwitches = new ClientResource("http://127.0.0.1:8080/wm/core/controller/switches/json");
    StringWriter sWriterSwitches = new StringWriter();

    // List all the devices (hosts) in the network
    ClientResource cResourceDevices = new ClientResource("http://127.0.0.1:8080/wm/device/");
    StringWriter sWriterDevices = new StringWriter();

    // List the statistics of the switches in the network
    ClientResource cResourceQueues = new ClientResource("http://127.0.0.1:8080/wm/core/switch/all/queue/json");
    StringWriter sWriterQueues = new StringWriter();

    // get JSON data about switches; the data is put in a string writer
    try {

        // Getting data from Floodlight as a JSON string

        cResourceSwitches.get(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).write(sWriterSwitches);
        cResourceDevices.get(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).write(sWriterDevices);

        cResourceQueues.get(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).write(sWriterQueues);

    } catch (ResourceException e) {
        request.setAttribute("error", "Connection with FLoodLight failed!");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/connectionError.jsp").forward(request, response);
        return;
    }

    // put data from string writer into a string object
    String switchesJson = sWriterSwitches.toString();
    String devicesJson = sWriterDevices.toString();
    String queueJson = sWriterQueues.toString();

    // map JSON data to Java objects
    // ObjectMapper converts between JSON - Java
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


    ArrayList<Switch> switches = mapper.readValue(switchesJson, new TypeReference<ArrayList<Switch>>() {
    });
    ArrayList<Device> devices = mapper.readValue(devicesJson, new TypeReference<ArrayList<Device>>() {
    });

    ArrayList<Switch> queues = mapper.readValue(queueJson, new TypeReference<ArrayList<Switch>>() {

    });

    // put objects in the request so we can use them later in the JSP
    request.setAttribute("switches", switches);
    request.setAttribute("devices", devices);
    request.setAttribute("queues", queues);

    // redirect to the jsp
    request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/showInfo.jsp").forward(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
        IOException {

}
```

}

Comment: Try adding the `List<Whatever>` into a DTO object and serialize this DTO for the communication.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The Switch class in  "ArrayList" can't be used for switch statistics. A new class has to be implemented, which returns the values in

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/wm/core/switch/all/queue/json
```

URI.